# Not able to get array in thymeleaf th:each method

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Controller has,

```
    package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

/**
 * GreetingController
 */
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String greeting(Model model) {
        String[] dataa = {"TATA", "CTS", "MTS"};
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        model.addAttribute("datta", dataa);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Index Page2</h2>
    <h1 th:text="${message}"></h1>
    <ul th:each="item : ${datta}">
        <li th:text="${item}"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Not usnderstanidng why I am not able to the dataa array in index.html.
Is that possible to get key value set th:each.

Comment: Change your Thymeleaf expression to this: `${dataa}"`, so that is matches the value in the model. Or change the model to match Thymeleaf: `model.addAttribute("datta", datta);`.

Comment: typed mistakely. Edited.. Even I am tried with model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!"); It prints ${message} in view html. Any idea on this?

Comment: If you view the source in the browser and see `${expression}`s, then you haven't set up Thymeleaf correctly and it's not processing your views.

Answer (score 1):

Typing mistake in your variable name use either **dataa** or **datta** at both places

In Java, you passed the attribute **dataa**

```
model.addAttribute("dataa", datta);
```

But while fetching in html, the variable name is **datta**

```
<ul th:each="item : ${datta}">
```

Comment: typed mistakely. Edited.

Comment: I checked with the same code you mentioned in my local machine, it's working fine. I can see values in browser. I think the problem may be the configuration. More code of both java and html files would be helpful to identify the issue.

Comment: Again, it's working fine in my local. Have you included the thymeleaf dependecy in pom.xml if you are using as maven project. Can I have a look at your pom.xml file

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency> ... etc

Comment: I am not using viewrepository. index routing with getmapping. Is that the issue?

Comment: Got the solution. I didnt call index page. just tried localhost:8080. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just cross-check if the correct package for Model class is imported. Not sure!
2. Make sure index file in /src/main/resources/templates

Comment: Yes, both got verified. 
1. pom.xml added dependecy.
2. Imported sprintframework.ui.model.
3. added index.html in resource template folder.
4. added xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org".in index html file
Apart from that anything needs to be done?